# Get Request Body from a Java 11 HttpRequest

Tags: java

I have a function that takes in a [java.net.http.HttpRequest](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.html), logs it, sends it via a java.net.http.HttpClient, logs the response and returns the java.net.http.HttpResponse.

I am having a little bit of trouble accessing the HttpRequest's body. Is this even possible?

```
public HttpResponse<String> send(HttpRequest req) throws Exception
{
   log(req.body()); // this method doesn't exist
   HttpResponse<String> rsp = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(req, BodyHandlers.ofString());
   log(rsp.body()); // this method does
   return rsp;
}
```

I would like to avoid having to pass the body as a parameter if it is already encoded in the HttpRequest, if possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash, that's for a different class. HttpServletRequest is not Java 11's new HttpRequest.

Comment: `req.bodyPublisher().getOrThrow()` might be a start.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn, I tried this route and the BodyPublishers, from what I can tell, is also problematic for getting the original request. There's some things in there about subscriptions, but I think that's for the response, not the request.

Comment: No, the subscriptions are exactly how you go about it. You add a subscription before you call the client, so it passes all it passes to the client also to your subscription.

Comment: So there's no way to get the request body for logging until after the client is called then?

Comment: Did anyone solve this?  I have exactly the same problem, and it seems silly that I have this HttpRequest object that I can't access the body....  why is there no "byte[] getBody()" method?

Comment: Im stucked in same point